# Runescape application using wine

Tags: wine, runescape

I downloaded runescape mmorpg and play it using wine. it continuously shuts down on me. It shows the following:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x7d2eb1d0).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:7d2eb1d0 ESP:060dc7f0 EBP:060dc828 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:7d3e7000 ECX:060dc840 EDX:7d3e29e0
 ESI:060dc870 EDI:0b97a1ac
Stack dump:
0x060dc7f0:  0b97a168 7d3a4994 060dc86c 0b93a1ac
0x060dc800:  4d430003 00000000 060dc828 7d2e9e4d
0x060dc810:  0b97a178 7d3a4994 060dc840 7d3e7000
0x060dc820:  0b9386d4 060dc870 060dc898 7d2ccf3e
0x060dc830:  00000000 7d2cbb50 00000000 7d2ccf3e
0x060dc840:  0b97a1ac 060dc870 060dc86c 7d3109ff
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7d2eb1d0 in mshtml (+0x2b1d0) (0x060dc828)
  1 0x7d2ccf3e in mshtml (+0xcf3d) (0x060dc898)
  2 0x7d2ce5bb in mshtml (+0xe5ba) (0x060dc908)
  3 0x7d2cecda in mshtml (+0xecd9) (0x060dc978)
  4 0x7c6be54f in jscript (+0x2e54e) (0x060dca08)
  5 0x7c6c0c1b in jscript (+0x30c1a) (0x060dca48)
  6 0x7c6c61c4 in jscript (+0x361c3) (0x060dcac8)
  7 0x7c6c9649 in jscript (+0x39648) (0x060dcb48)
  8 0x7c6ca196 in jscript (+0x3a195) (0x060dcb98)
  9 0x7c6bc8a9 in jscript (+0x2c8a8) (0x060dcbe8)
  10 0x7c6bc9c1 in jscript (+0x2c9c0) (0x060dccc8)
  11 0x7c6bd12c in jscript (+0x2d12b) (0x060dcd28)
  12 0x7c6bd95b in jscript (+0x2d95a) (0x060dce08)
  13 0x7c6c210e in jscript (+0x3210d) (0x060dce78)
  14 0x7c6c61c4 in jscript (+0x361c3) (0x060dcef8)
  15 0x7c6c9649 in jscript (+0x39648) (0x060dcf78)
  16 0x7c6ca196 in jscript (+0x3a195) (0x060dcfc8)
  17 0x7c6bc8a9 in jscript (+0x2c8a8) (0x060dd018)
  18 0x7c6bc9c1 in jscript (+0x2c9c0) (0x060dd0f8)
  19 0x7c6bd12c in jscript (+0x2d12b) (0x060dd158)
  20 0x7c6bd95b in jscript (+0x2d95a) (0x060dd238)
  21 0x7c6c210e in jscript (+0x3210d) (0x060dd2a8)
  22 0x7c6c61c4 in jscript (+0x361c3) (0x060dd328)
  23 0x7c6c9649 in jscript (+0x39648) (0x060dd3a8)
  24 0x7c6ca196 in jscript (+0x3a195) (0x060dd3f8)
  25 0x7c6bc8a9 in jscript (+0x2c8a8) (0x060dd448)
  26 0x7c6bc9c1 in jscript (+0x2c9c0) (0x060dd528)
  27 0x7c6bd12c in jscript (+0x2d12b) (0x060dd588)
  28 0x7c6bd95b in jscript (+0x2d95a) (0x060dd668)
  29 0x7c6c210e in jscript (+0x3210d) (0x060dd6d8)
  30 0x7c6c61c4 in jscript (+0x361c3) (0x060dd758)
  31 0x7c6c9649 in jscript (+0x39648) (0x060dd7d8)
  32 0x7c6ca196 in jscript (+0x3a195) (0x060dd828)
  33 0x7c6bc8a9 in jscript (+0x2c8a8) (0x060dd878)
  34 0x7c6bc9c1 in jscript (+0x2c9c0) (0x060dd958)
  35 0x7c6bd12c in jscript (+0x2d12b) (0x060dd9b8)
  36 0x7c6bd95b in jscript (+0x2d95a) (0x060dda98)
  37 0x7c6c210e in jscript (+0x3210d) (0x060ddb08)
  38 0x7c6c61c4 in jscript (+0x361c3) (0x060ddb88)
  39 0x7c6c9649 in jscript (+0x39648) (0x060ddc08)
  40 0x7c6ca196 in jscript (+0x3a195) (0x060ddc58)
  41 0x7c6bc8a9 in jscript (+0x2c8a8) (0x060ddca8)
  42 0x7c6bc9c1 in jscript (+0x2c9c0) (0x060ddd88)
  43 0x7c6bd12c in jscript (+0x2d12b) (0x060ddde8)
  44 0x7c6bd95b in jscript (+0x2d95a) (0x060ddec8)
  45 0x7c6c210e in jscript (+0x3210d) (0x060ddf38)
  46 0x7c6c61c4 in jscript (+0x361c3) (0x060ddfb8)
  47 0x7c6c9649 in jscript (+0x39648) (0x060de038)
  48 0x7c6ca196 in jscript (+0x3a195) (0x060de088)
  49 0x7c6bd1d4 in jscript (+0x2d1d3) (0x060de0e8)
  50 0x7c6bd641 in jscript (+0x2d640) (0x060de1a8)
  51 0x7c6ba0d8 in jscript (+0x2a0d7) (0x060de228)
  52 0x7d378765 in mshtml (+0xb8764) (0x060de2d8)
  53 0x7ecd94ea WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x060de318)
  54 0x7ecd9c26 in user32 (+0x99c25) (0x060de368)
  55 0x7ecdb526 in user32 (+0x9b525) (0x060de818)
  56 0x7ecdc3f3 in user32 (+0x9c3f2) (0x060de868)
  57 0x7ec9d1b5 DispatchMessageA+0xb4() in user32 (0x060de968)
  58 0x05ea1ecd in browsercontrol (+0x1ecc) (0x060de998)
  59 0x05ea3eaa in browsercontrol (+0x3ea9) (0x060de9d0)
  60 0x05ea3f46 in browsercontrol (+0x3f45) (0x060de9d8)
  61 0x7bc799b0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x060de9e8)
  62 0x7bc7c93d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x060deab8)
  63 0x7bc7998e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x060dead8)
  64 0x7bc82dce in ntdll (+0x72dcd) (0x060df358)
  65 0xb7502f70 start_thread+0xcf() in libpthread.so.0 (0x060df428)
  66 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  67 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  68 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  69 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  70 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  71 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  72 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  73 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  74 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  75 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  76 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  77 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  78 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  79 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  80 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  81 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  82 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  83 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  84 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  85 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  86 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  87 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  88 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  89 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  90 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  91 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  92 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  93 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  94 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  95 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  96 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  97 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  98 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  99 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  100 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  101 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  102 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  103 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  104 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  105 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  106 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  107 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  108 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  109 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  110 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  111 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  112 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  113 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  114 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  115 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  116 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  117 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  118 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  119 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  120 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  121 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  122 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  123 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  124 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  125 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  126 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  127 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  128 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  129 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  130 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  131 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  132 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  133 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  134 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  135 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  136 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  137 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  138 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  139 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  140 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  141 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  142 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  143 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  144 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  145 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  146 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  147 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  148 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  149 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  150 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  151 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  152 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  153 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  154 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  155 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  156 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  157 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  158 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  159 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  160 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  161 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  162 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  163 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  164 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  165 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  166 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  167 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  168 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  169 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  170 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  171 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  172 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  173 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  174 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  175 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  176 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  177 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  178 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  179 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  180 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  181 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  182 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  183 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  184 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  185 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  186 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  187 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  188 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  189 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  190 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  191 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  192 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  193 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  194 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  195 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  196 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  197 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  198 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  199 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  200 0xb743350e __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x7d2eb1d0: movl    0x0(%eax),%edx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (239 modules)
PE    340000-  360000   Deferred        java
PE    390000-  3a3000   Deferred        zip
PE    400000-  406000   Deferred        jagexlauncher
PE   3a80000- 3ae6000   Deferred        freetype
PE   3af0000- 3b04000   Deferred        net
PE   4c40000- 4d81000   Deferred        awt
PE   5390000- 5415000   Deferred        fontmanager
PE   5420000- 542f000   Deferred        nio
PE   57f0000- 5811000   Deferred        jpeg
PE   5820000- 582a000   Deferred        jsound
PE   5830000- 5839000   Deferred        jsoundds
PE   58a0000- 58c6000   Deferred        jaclib
PE   59f0000- 5a06000   Deferred        jagdx
PE   5a10000- 5a2a000   Deferred        jaggl
PE   5ea0000- 5eb4000   Export          browsercontrol
PE   5ec0000- 5ec6000   Deferred        jawt
PE   6280000- 7bb3000   Deferred        xul
PE   7bc0000- 7bd1000   Deferred        mozalloc
PE   7be0000- 7c1a000   Deferred        mozglue
PE   7c20000- 7c5b000   Deferred        nspr4
PE   7c60000- 7cfb000   Deferred        mozsqlite3
PE   7d00000- 7d12000   Deferred        plds4
PE   7d20000- 7d32000   Deferred        plc4
PE   7d40000- 7d67000   Deferred        nssutil3
PE   7d70000- 7e5f000   Deferred        nss3
PE   7e60000- 7ea0000   Deferred        ssl3
PE   7ea0000- 7ecc000   Deferred        smime3
PE   7fd0000- 7fe1000   Deferred        unpack
PE   8000000- 8324000   Deferred        jvm
PE   8330000- 87ac000   Deferred        gkmedias
PE   87b0000- 8bfc000   Deferred        mozjs
PE  10000000-1000c000   Deferred        verify
PE  78aa0000-78b5e000   Deferred        msvcr100
ELF 79bbe000-79bd7000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  79bc0000-79bd7000   \               msacm32
ELF 79bd7000-79ccd000   Deferred        libasound.so.2
ELF 79ccd000-79ce3000   Deferred        midimap<elf>
  \-PE  79cd0000-79ce3000   \               midimap
ELF 79ce3000-79d13000   Deferred        winealsa<elf>
  \-PE  79cf0000-79d13000   \               winealsa
ELF 79e30000-79e45000   Deferred        avicap32<elf>
  \-PE  79e40000-79e45000   \               avicap32
ELF 79e45000-79e6c000   Deferred        devenum<elf>
  \-PE  79e50000-79e6c000   \               devenum
ELF 7a86c000-7a8a3000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7a8a3000-7a8ae000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7a997000-7a9a5000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7a9a5000-7a9ad000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7a9ad000-7a9cf000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7a9cf000-7af28000   Deferred        i915_dri.so
ELF 7af28000-7af32000   Deferred        libnih-dbus.so.1
ELF 7af32000-7af4b000   Deferred        libnih.so.1
ELF 7af4b000-7af69000   Deferred        libcgmanager.so.0
ELF 7af69000-7af7c000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7af7c000-7af89000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7af89000-7af90000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7af90000-7afa8000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7afa8000-7afc1000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7afc1000-7b053000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7b069000-7b090000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  7b070000-7b090000   \               dxgi
ELF 7b090000-7b0c2000   Deferred        wbemprox<elf>
  \-PE  7b0a0000-7b0c2000   \               wbemprox
ELF 7b0c2000-7b137000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7b0d0000-7b137000   \               ddraw
ELF 7b137000-7b246000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7b150000-7b246000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b246000-7b386000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7b250000-7b386000   \               wined3d
ELF 7b386000-7b3c3000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7b390000-7b3c3000   \               d3d9
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7ba5e000-7ba62000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7ba88000-7bc00000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bcdd000-7bd09000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7bd09000-7bd3d000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7bd3d000-7bdaf000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7bdaf000-7be1e000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-4.0.so
ELF 7be1e000-7be6d000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7be6d000-7be95000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7be70000-7be95000   \               winepulse
ELF 7be95000-7beb7000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7bea0000-7beb7000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7beb7000-7bf00000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7bec0000-7bf00000   \               dsound
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bf06000-7bf0f000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7c405000-7c40c000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7c40c000-7c566000   Deferred        libxml2.so.2
ELF 7c566000-7c624000   Deferred        msxml3<elf>
  \-PE  7c570000-7c624000   \               msxml3
ELF 7c675000-7c68a000   Deferred        t2embed<elf>
  \-PE  7c680000-7c68a000   \               t2embed
ELF 7c68a000-7c724000   Dwarf           jscript<elf>
  \-PE  7c690000-7c724000   \               jscript
ELF 7cbd8000-7cc08000   Deferred        p11-kit-trust.so
ELF 7cc08000-7cc11000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7cc11000-7cc18000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7cc18000-7cc1d000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7cc1d000-7cc68000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7cc68000-7cca4000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7cca4000-7ccb8000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7ccb8000-7cd3f000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7cd3f000-7cd4b000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7cd4b000-7cd50000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7cd50000-7cd80000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7cd80000-7ce3e000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7ce3e000-7ce50000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7ce50000-7ce5e000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7ce5e000-7cf24000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7cf24000-7cf69000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7cf69000-7cfd6000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7cfd6000-7cfee000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7cfe0000-7cfee000   \               userenv
ELF 7cfee000-7d05f000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d000000-7d05f000   \               setupapi
ELF 7d05f000-7d092000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7d070000-7d092000   \               secur32
ELF 7d092000-7d0ad000   Deferred        rasapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7d0a0000-7d0ad000   \               rasapi32
ELF 7d0ad000-7d0da000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7d0b0000-7d0da000   \               netapi32
ELF 7d0da000-7d142000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7d0e0000-7d142000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7d142000-7d182000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7d150000-7d182000   \               winspool
ELF 7d182000-7d26d000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d190000-7d26d000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7d26d000-7d293000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d270000-7d293000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7d293000-7d2af000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7d2a0000-7d2af000   \               wsock32
ELF 7d2af000-7d3f7000   Dwarf           mshtml<elf>
  \-PE  7d2c0000-7d3f7000   \               mshtml
ELF 7d3f7000-7d62a000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7d400000-7d62a000   \               shell32
ELF 7d62a000-7d62d000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d62d000-7d637000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7d637000-7d642000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7d642000-7d680000   Deferred        libxslt.so.1
ELF 7d680000-7d6a6000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7d6a8000-7d6ac000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7d6ac000-7d6b2000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d6b2000-7d6b5000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d6bc000-7d6da000   Deferred        msxml<elf>
  \-PE  7d6c0000-7d6da000   \               msxml
ELF 7d6da000-7d71c000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  7d6e0000-7d71c000   \               rsaenh
ELF 7d71c000-7d7eb000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7d730000-7d7eb000   \               crypt32
ELF 7d8eb000-7d900000   Deferred        schannel<elf>
  \-PE  7d8f0000-7d900000   \               schannel
ELF 7da00000-7da04000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7da04000-7da17000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7da17000-7da58000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7da20000-7da58000   \               usp10
ELF 7da58000-7db00000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7da70000-7db00000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7dc00000-7dc04000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7dc04000-7dc80000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7dc10000-7dc80000   \               wininet
ELF 7dc80000-7dcfa000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dc90000-7dcfa000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7dd79000-7dd8e000   Deferred        rasdlg<elf>
  \-PE  7dd80000-7dd8e000   \               rasdlg
ELF 7dd8e000-7ddb6000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7dd90000-7ddb6000   \               mpr
ELF 7ddb6000-7de58000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7ddc0000-7de58000   \               urlmon
ELF 7de58000-7decb000   Deferred        ieframe<elf>
  \-PE  7de60000-7decb000   \               ieframe
ELF 7dee9000-7df06000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7df06000-7df1e000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7df1e000-7df25000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7df25000-7df29000   Deferred        libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
ELF 7df2b000-7df3f000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7df30000-7df3f000   \               msimg32
ELF 7dfa1000-7dfd7000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7dfb0000-7dfd7000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7dff9000-7e100000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e000000-7e100000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e224000-7e25b000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7e230000-7e25b000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7e25b000-7e280000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e260000-7e280000   \               imm32
ELF 7e280000-7e3b6000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2a0000-7e3b6000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e3b6000-7e3e1000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3c0000-7e3e1000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e3e1000-7e462000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e3f0000-7e462000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e462000-7e59e000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e480000-7e59e000   \               ole32
ELF 7e59e000-7e658000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e5b0000-7e658000   \               winmm
ELF 7e658000-7e65e000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7e65e000-7e669000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7e669000-7e67a000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7e67a000-7e67e000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e67e000-7e689000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e689000-7e694000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e694000-7e69a000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e69a000-7e69e000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e69e000-7e6a5000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e6a5000-7e6a9000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e6a9000-7e6cb000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e6cb000-7e7ff000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e7ff000-7e812000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e812000-7e826000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e820000-7e826000   \               psapi
ELF 7e828000-7e8ba000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7e8ba000   \               winex11
ELF 7e921000-7e94a000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e94a000-7e985000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e985000-7e9ad000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e9ad000-7e9c7000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e9c7000-7ea66000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7ea7c000-7ea96000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7ea80000-7ea96000   \               version
ELF 7ea96000-7eb08000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eaa0000-7eb08000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eb08000-7ec25000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb10000-7ec25000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ec25000-7ed7f000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec40000-7ed7f000   \               user32
ELF 7ef7f000-7ef8c000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef8c000-7ef98000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef98000-7efb1000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efb1000-7efba000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efba000-7f000000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF b7347000-b74f6000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF b74f6000-b74fb000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b74fc000-b7518000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF b752e000-b76e3000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b76e5000-b7707000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b7707000-b7708000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\jagexlauncher\jagexlauncher\bin\JagexLauncher.exe
    00000069    1
    00000068    0
    0000000d    0
    00000036    0
    00000051    0
    00000050    0
    00000019    0
    0000000b    0
    00000052    0
    00000016    0
    00000048    0
    0000003a    0
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    0000005a    0
    00000058   -2
    00000059   -2
    00000035   -2
    00000018    0
    00000067    0
    00000066   -2
    00000065    0
    00000064    2
    00000063    2
    00000062   15
    00000061   -2
    00000060    0
    0000005f    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005d   15
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    00000055   -2
    00000054   -2
    00000053    0
    0000004f   -2
    0000004e   -2
    0000004d   -2
    0000004c   -2
    0000004b    0
    0000004a   -2
    00000049   -2
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040   -1
    0000003f    0
    0000003e    0
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    00000039    0 <==
    00000038    0
    00000037    2
    00000034   -2
    00000033   -2
    00000032   -2
    00000031    2
    00000030    2
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    2
    0000002d    2
    0000002c    2
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    1
    00000029    2
    00000028    2
    00000027    2
    00000026    2
    00000025    2
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    00000021    0
    0000001a    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001c    0
00000022 explorer.exe
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
```

System information:

```
Wine build: wine-1.6.2
Platform: i386
Host system: Linux
Host version: 3.16.0-30-generic
```

Any ideas on what i can do to fix this or if it is even fixable?

Answer (score 1):

The Original RuneScape doesn't work using Wine as of now.

To play RuneScape on ubuntu,you can install the [Unix RuneScape Client](https://launchpad.net/~hikariknight/+archive/ubuntu/unix-runescape-client).

**Some Instructions to install Unix RuneScape Client:**

1) Add the PPA for URSC in the terminal by using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client`

2) Use `sudo apt-get update`

3) Finnaly, use `sudo apt-get install unix-runescape-client`

And there you have it. Note that RuneScape, RuneScape Beta, OSRS, and some of Jagex's "special" games (from funorb) will play now.